# Django-reversion manually create version

Tags: python, django, django-reversion

Let's say I want to create a version of an object only in certain conditions, for example when 'status' field of object of class 'mymodel' is being changed to 'submitted'. How can I do this?

```
class MyModel(AbstractModel):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs) -> bool:
        if self.status == 'submitted':
            #TODO: create version. HOW??????
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Also how can I suppress automatic version creation on every save?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way:

```
with reversion.create_revision(manage_manually=True, atomic=False):
    reversion.add_to_revision(self)
    self.save()
```